# Installing latest version of GNU Octave when I have already installed other version

Tags: apt, software-installation, software-uninstall, octave

I have installed Gnu Octave by using `apt-get install octave`.
This installed version 4.0.3 on my machine.

I want to install the latest available version. How can I:

1. Uninstall the version I have?
2. Install the latest version?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu do you use ? \\ if you are using zesty (17.04) you can use this commands for adding this repository `sudo sed -i 's/zesty/xenial/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/octave-ubuntu-stable-zesty.list && sudo apt update`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For uninstalling GNU Octave you can run this command:

```
sudo apt purge octave
```

But you don't need to remove and then install latest version of Octave.

You can easily upgrade that package with this commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:octave/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install octave
```

These commands upgrade Octave to latest stable version of this software (with no need to remove current version).

Comment: After running this, it says: octave is already the newest version (4.0.3-3ubuntu1).
However on octaves webpage it says that 4.2.1 has been released :(

Comment: If a new software is released upstream (by the original authors) it is not automatically in the Ubuntu repository. The Ubuntu maintainers have to create the packages and so on. Within a Ubuntu release (i.e. 18.04) packages only get security updates and few packages get major updates like firefox, thunderbird, chromium.

Comment: It worked. Successfully installed Octave 4.2.2 on Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can run the newest version of Octave (5.1.0 in March 2019) by running it as a Flatpack app. "[Flatpack](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak) is a system for building, distributing, and running sandboxed desktop applications on Linux."

The installation procedure is described here: https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.octave.Octave at the bottom of the page.

A more complete set of commands looks like the following section:

If you are on Ubuntu 16.04, You have to install flatpack first, then run Octave:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
sudo apt install flatpak
# optional line, AFAIK (pulls in Gnome deps?):
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak  
# this line possibly required on Debian systems
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo  
flatpak install flathub org.octave.Octave
flatpak run org.octave.Octave --gui
```

This downloads about 900 MB from the internet.

For convenience in starting Octave from the command line, you can create the files `/usr/share/octave` with the contents

```
#!/bin/sh
flatpak run org.octave.Octave --gui
```

and `/usr/share/octave-cli` with content

```
#!/bin/sh
flatpak run org.octave.Octave
```

Comment: on my Debian stretch (9, stable) you also must add the repo, which is done by  

    `flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo`